# Chrome extension: Prevent chrome.tabCapture.capture choppy sound by increasing buffer size?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-audio-api

It's seems like audio capturing using [`chrome.tabCapture.capture`](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) can produce some choppy sounds.

There is already a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=555615) for this.

Is it possible to increase the buffer that receives the captured stream in order to prevent the stutter, or does the `tabCapture` method already defines a buffer?

Basic capturing:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }, function (stream) {
        var ctx = new AudioContext();
        var output = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        output.connect(ctx.destination)
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, but the choppy sound seems to disappear if you create the `AudioContext` with a `LatencyHint` argument:

```
new AudioContext({latencyHint: 'playback'});
```

Here you can read more about it: [MDN `AudioContext.AudioContext()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext#Parameters)

> latencyHint: This value identifies type of playback, which affects tradeoffs between audio output latency and power consumption. The prefered values are "balanced", "interactive", and **"playback"**, with the default value: "interactive". These values mean "balance audio output latency and power consumption", "provide lowest audio output latency as possible without glitching", and **"prioritize sustained playback without interruption over audio output latency"**. You can also specify double value for the number of seconds of latency, for finer control.

Comment: The argument is case sensitive. The L in latency has to be lowercase or it never actually changes the value. You can confirm its value by checking the baseLatency member of the object you just created.

Comment: Improved performance quite a bit for me, now just a tiny glitch a no change of audio rate